# What does "3~4 times a charm" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I was enjoying the game and found this note:

> 3~4 times a charm! 3~4 taps at your friends' café everyday.

[image: What does "3~4 times a charm" mean?]

I don't know what it means.

Comment: As an English speaker, I don't know what it means either.

Answer (score 2):

1. [third time's the charm](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/third+time%27s+the+charm) is a normal idiom - in fairy-tales all things comes in 3 and the third time something will happen. Here is the joke that you can have 3 or 4 times the charm.
2. If the game involves tapping some thing, you can have 3 or 4 taps.
3. [Tapped beer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer_tap). Enjoy 3-4 different types  of tapped beer in the cafe.
4. Depending on the type of game, it could be sexual innuendo. To tap someone is to have sex with them.

Comment: Maybe in this game you are able to ‘help’ your friends by tapping on their machines, ect. (I’ve seen this concept in multiple games)

Comment: Is there an English dialect where *taps* means "beers"?

Comment: Who said the game is English ? All your base belong to us... anyway updated